# What is, (and what isn't) "kinetic replication" as it applies to molecules and to living organisms?

Tags: molecular-biology, terminology, dna-replication

CNN's [World's first living robots can now reproduce, scientists say](https://edition.cnn.com/2021/11/29/americas/xenobots-self-replicating-robots-scn/index.html) describes "xenobots"; clusters of stem cells that move around and by this motion occasionally push enough free stem cells together such that they form a new one, at least that's my understanding.

The article says:

> "Most people think of robots as made of metals and ceramics but it's not so much what a robot is made from but what it does, which is act on its own on behalf of people," said Josh Bongard, a computer science professor and robotics expert at the University of Vermont and lead author of the study.
>
> "In that way it's a robot but it's also clearly an organism made from genetically unmodified frog cell."
>
> Bongard said they found that the xenobots, which were initially sphere-shaped and made from around 3,000 cells, could replicate. But it happened rarely and only in specific circumstances. **The xenobots used "kinetic replication" -- a process that is known to occur at the molecular level but has never been observed before at the scale of whole cells or organisms, Bongard said.**

*Interestingly* the CNN article actually links to the new paper in PNAS [Kinematic self-replication in reconfigurable organisms](https://www.pnas.org/content/118/49/e2112672118) which uses "kinematic" rather than "kinetic".

There is no easy to find Wikipedia article titled "kinetic replication" and the phrase does not appear here in Biology SE nor in Chemistry SE.

I found the 2009 PLOS Computational Biology article [Investigating the Conformational Stability of Prion Strains through a Kinetic Replication Model](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000420) which relates the structural stability of the prion aggregates to the rate of replication.

I also found the 1996 Biophysical Chemistry paper [Prionics or The kinetic basis of prion diseases](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0301462296022508?via%3Dihub).

And in Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical (2015) there is [Hidden percolation transition in kinetic replication process](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/48/13/135003).

Nothing jumps out to me as a clear definition.

I found searching for the term to be somewhat confounding because the word "kinetics" relates to the measurement of reaction rates as well as to focus on the actual physical interaction between individual molecules (or organisms) which I think is what's being referred to here. Lots of search results including "kinetic" and "replication" but very few on the combined term.

So I'd like to ask for an answer that explores the term "kinetic replication", hopefully cites a formal definition or at least outlines a generally accepted one, and offers a way to distinguish when the replication of a molecule or an organism is "kinetic replication" and when it isn't.

**Question:** What is, (and what isn't) "kinetic replication" as it applies to molecules and to living organisms?

Comment: I chose the `replication` tag but it automatically switches to `dna-replication` which I am not sure applies here.

Comment: I upvoted because: nice find. I suspect the answer may lie in a whimsical comment coining the term made to a journalist more than a hard-science definition. Google Ngram shows 0 results.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I updated a few minutes ago to add the link to the PNAS article which uses "kinematic self-replication" (a robotics term) rather than "kinetic replication". I'm surprised Ngram didn't at least pick up the two papers I've linked to, do they only search in books or do they also check journal articles?

Comment: I'm not certain. The reference which leapt out at me was to the superpower of one of the X-Men, hence the whimsey.

Comment: It seems to me, having watched the video in the CNN link, that what is being referred to might be [autocatalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocatalysis#cite_note-17): the concept that the product of a reaction can catalyze the same reaction.  Auto-proteolysis is a great example. Despite what Wikipedia says, autocatalysis as an explanation for the origin of life long predates 1995. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JSw5eq5eeg) for a great explanation by [Manfred Eigen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfred_Eigen), who received the Nobel prize in 1967

Comment: @user338907 excellent video and explanation, *thanks!*

Comment: @user338907 nobody has posted an answer yet, perhaps that link and a very brief summary of a few key points will work an an answer?